# How to get the ID of the last record you added and add it as foreign key to another record on another table

Tags: asp.net

I am creating a system that adds a child to a school's database but first I have to add the parent/ guardian and then proceed to child, because the guardian ID has to be a foreign key to the child's table...How do initialize the property of the Guardian ID in the child form with the newly added parent record ID in guardian table?
I am using ASP.NET

I hope you understand my question

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I suppose it depends on how you adding the reocrd?

But, as a general rule, this works:

```
       using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
        {
            string strSQL = "INSERT INTO tblHotels (HotelName, City, Province) " +
                            "VALUES(@Hotel, @City, @Province)";

            using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL, conn))
            {
                cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@Hotel", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = "Test HotelName";
                cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@City", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = "Test City";
                cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@Province", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = "Test Province";

                conn.Open();
                cmdSQL.ExecuteNonQuery();

                cmdSQL.CommandText = "SELECT @@IDENTITY";
                int NewPK = Convert.ToInt32(cmdSQL.ExecuteScalar());
                Debug.Print("New id = " + NewPK);

                // now add child reocrd
                strSQL = "INSERT INTO Bookings (Hotel_ID, BookingName) " +
                         "VALUES(@Hotel_ID, @BookName)";
                cmdSQL.CommandText = strSQL;
                cmdSQL.Parameters.Clear();
                cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@Hotel_ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = NewPK;
                cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@BookName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = "Albert Kallal";

                cmdSQL.ExecuteNonQuery();

            }
        }
```